# Application Page not reponding after 4.00 Minutes

Tags: 2013, application-pages, third-party-software

I have a SharePoint application page which is having a usercontrol and that user control is having RAD Controls and script managers.

The problem I am facing is that if the operation takes more than 4 minutes, like 4.01, then the page hangs. But in logs if we see then it is completing all the processes successfully.

We have changed the `Timeout` in Sharepoint App `web.config`, and layouts `web.config` but no luck.

The code:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 09, 14);

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            mrEditScreenBDO.ReportDate = dt;

            Logger("Started -----> " + startTime.ToString());

            mrEditScreenBL.GetDataFieldValues();

            Logger("GetDataFieldValues -----> " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            mrEditScreenBDO.AssetName = "Test";
            mrEditScreenBL.ProcessData();

            Logger("ProcessData -----> " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            TimeSpan timeTaken = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            Response.Write("Time taken to complete the process - "
                               + string.Format("{0:F0}", timeTaken.Minutes)
                               + " min " + string.Format("{0:F0}", timeTaken.Seconds) + " sec");
            Logger("Time taken to complete the process - "
                               + string.Format("{0:F0}", timeTaken.Minutes)
                               + " min " + string.Format("{0:F0}", timeTaken.Seconds) + " sec");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

public void Logger(string Log)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = "D:\\" + "MRLog.txt";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                //If it exists then append data to file
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("\n" + Log);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Write Line and creates a file if it is not there
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "\n" + Log + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In above code the `ProcessData()` function is interacting with a third party PI Server, fetching the data and doing operations locally.

If I do the operation on the machine where the application is created then it is working fine irrespective of the time taken. But outside the machine it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

There are two timeout properties in web.config

1. Upload
2. Download

Please make sure you have adjusted the correct one.

Comment: Both are 1500...should i increase it to more??

Comment: the time we enter in web.config is in milliseconds. You'll need to update it accordingly

Comment: I tried increasing it....but the result is still same...

Comment: what value did you gave?

Comment: 999999....i set....and also if there was a timeout issue then it would have thrown error...but here behindthe scenes the process is going on and at UI we are not able see any change

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/83c7215a-1523-4f83-a2fb-c474407a0888/how-to-set-the-session-timeout-for-sharepoint-web-application-?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

http://geekswithblogs.net/DennisBottjer/archive/2009/04/13/increase-sharepoint-execution-timeout.aspx

Comment: I hv already tried these things...problem is that if process takes more than 4 minutes then response will not come...i tried tracing it in fiddler and came to know